Family reunion in Heaven
Please there’s something that l have been wondering about for sometime now.
Please after the last Trumpet will we be able to see Family and Friends in Heaven.?  Thank you

1 Cor 15:51, 52 - Listen, I tell you a mystery: We will not all sleep,
but we will all be changed— in an instant, in the twinkling of an eye,
at the last trumpet. For the trumpet will sound, the dead will be
raised imperishable, and we will be changed.


Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for joining the group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.  Questions here need a specific bible passage to analyze.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I’m voting to close this question because
This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network, Christianity.SE.

Yes.

"Then Abraham gave up the ghost, and died in a good old age, an old man, and full of years; and was gathered to his people." (Gen. 25:8, KJV)


"And these are the years of the life of Ishmael, an hundred and thirty and seven years: and he gave up the ghost and died; and was gathered unto his people." (Gen. 25:17, KJV)


"And Isaac gave up the ghost, and died, and was gathered unto his people, being old and full of days: and his sons Esau and Jacob buried him." (Gen. 25:39, KJV)

See also Gen. 49:29, 33; Num. 20:26; Deu. 32:50.  Consider the image of Lazarus in Abraham's Bosom in Luke 16:22.  1 Thess. 4:17 describes the process whereby God gathers together the saints as they die and pass from this realm to be taken where our loved ones who have gone before us already are in heaven.
Those who are in Christ have the hope within us to be together with all those that love the Lord in heaven.

"Precious in the sight of the Lord is the death of his saints." (Psa. 116:15, KJV)


+1... Of course, contrary arguments can be made but I sure hope you are right. Quite a few people believe that since people don't marry in the resurrection, then marriages are dissolved and so are familiar bonds. But for me, It wouldn't be heaven without family and friends.

Marriage vow / covenant is dissolved at death... death do us part... but that does not mean that we are not still brother and sister in Christ.  The family relation may not be there any longer... mother / daughter; father / son all convert to children of God. We will remain His children throughout eternity.

If we are created in God's image, then it seems to me that God would want us to be eternal parents to our children, just as God is.

This question would be better asked in Christianity.SE, as it asks about a specific doctrine held by many, but not all, denominations.
From a Biblical hermeneutical point of view, there is no reason to believe the basic assumption made by this question.
Nothing in the Bible indicates that people will ever go to Heaven.
The Bible in fact says very little about Heaven.
The Gospels record Jesus's time on Earth, and what they say about Heaven is very sparse:

Matthew uses the expression "Kingdom of Heaven" as a euphemism for "Kingdom of God".
The first and second heavens are the Earth's air and the vast space of the physical universe.
The third Heaven is the spiritual realm of God, the angels, etc.
No human but Jesus has been to Heaven (though John and others have been given visions of it).
The reward of the saved is currently kept in God's Heaven.
The resurrection of the dead will be into the Kingdom of God, here on Earth, not in Heaven.

The Gospels say nothing about Heaven that could be used to derive any doctrine about going to God's Heaven after death.
That belief is additional doctrine, not from exegesis of the scriptures.

The "last trumpet" is a term used frequently in the NT to denote the second coming of Jesus at the great final resurrection of the dead.

Matt 24:30, 31 - At that time the sign of the Son of Man will appear in heaven, and all the tribes of the earth will mourn. They will see the Son of Man coming on the clouds of heaven, with power and great glory. And He will send out His angels with a loud trumpet call, and they will gather His elect from the four winds, from one end of the heavens to the other.
1 Cor 15:51, 52 - Listen, I tell you a mystery: We will not all sleep, but we will all be changed— in an instant, in the twinkling of an eye, at the last trumpet. For the trumpet will sound, the dead will be raised imperishable, and we will be changed.
1 Thess 4:16, 17 - For the Lord Himself will descend from heaven with a loud command, with the voice of an archangel, and with the trumpet of God, and the dead in Christ will be the first to rise. After that, we who are alive and remain will be caught up together with them in the clouds to meet the Lord in the air. And so we will always be with the Lord.

In Rev 1:10, the sound of the trumpet appears to closely associated with the voice of Jesus.
We note that this great resurrection of the saints associated with the "last trumpet" involves a bodily resurrection which Paul goes to some lengths to explain in 1 Cor 15:39-50.  That is, just as Jesus ascended bodily and will return bodily (Acts 1:11) so we will be raised bodily with incorruptible bodies (1 Cor 15:53) and thus we will be recognized.
However, the far more important truth is stated in 1 Cor 13:12 -

Now we see but a dim reflection as in a mirror; then we shall see face
to face. Now I know in part; then I shall know fully, even as I am
fully known.

We will recognize Jesus and see Him face to face, Rev 22:4.

The last trump was the tekiah gedolah, the last shofar blast was the last one on the Feast of Trumpets sounded from the temple in Jerusalem on the 1st of Tishri.  That temple was destroyed in AD 70.  The last trump, the last shofar was sounded when that temple was destroyed at the coming of the Lord in judgment of Jerusalem in AD 70.  There is no temple in Jerusalem to sound another last trump.  Jesus' disciples knew the meaning of that phrase for the last trump, & knew it meant the 1st of Tishri for that temple to fall.
